# Update Property of Object in list in ForEach

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I have a `List(Of SomeObject)` that I enumerate over using a `For Each` loop. This `SomeObject` contains a Property that references another Object, as such

```
Class SomeObject
Public Property Another As AnotherObject
Get
    Return _another
End Get
Set (byval value as Integer)
_another = value
End Set
End Property

dim _another As New AnotherObject()
End Class
```

The question I have is whether updating AnotherObject property of SomeObject is valid within a For Each loop.

As such

```
Dim newanother As New AnotherObject()

For Each el As SomeObject in myobjects
  el.Another = newanother
Next
```

Is this valid?
If not, what is a valid way to do it? (ordinary for loop perhaps?)

Comment: Why wouldn't this be valid? What concerns you about it? You're not adding/removing items from the collection, or even altering the object's reference.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I am altering the reference, its pointing to a new object, but yes you're right, I'm not changing the collection. I guess my worries were unjustified...

Comment: I don't see how you're altering the reference. At least, you're not changing the object reference of the objects you're iterating through. You're changing the object reference of a *public property* of those objects. That's a completely different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're just changing the value of a property that is correct!!!, you can doit inside a cycle scope or not, beeing your proprty type a object or a system type.

what you cannot do, is change the collection inside the iteration scope!